# Analog of 'arguments.callee' in Lua

Tags: function, lua, self-reference

Is there a way to refer to the currently executing anonymous function in Lua? Just like we can do in JavaScript with `arguments.callee`.

E.g.:

```
local function newLiftAnimator(obj)
  local count = 0
  return function(event)
    -- animate obj's properties here on each "enterFrame" event
    obj.y = obj.y - 1
    count = count + 1
    -- when done, remove event listener
    if count >= 100 then
      Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", **<this_function>**)
    end
  end
end

Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", newLiftAnimator(ball))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
local f
f=function (event) ... Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", f) ... end
return f
```

Answer (score 2):

Never mind. After reading [this old message](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2004-07/msg00262.html) in Lua's mailing list, I came up with an obvious solution:

```
local function newLiftAnimator(obj)
  ...
  local function animator()
    ...
    Runtime:removeEventListener("enterFrame", animator)
  end
  return animator
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is using:

```
debug.getinfo(1,'f').func
```